# how can i import&export excel to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ado.net

I can't find the way to Import and Export Excel data to SQL server in C# using ADO.Net connection  i try this code to export but it didn't work i can't found the file in computer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ImportAndExport
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn;
            string connectionString = null;
            string sql = null;
            string data = null;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            connectionString = "data source=DESKTOP-I5MGTGH\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=dbStkMaamoonKhalidIssue;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Person";
            SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dscmd.Fill(ds);

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file E:\\Abd El-Rahman\\csharp.net-informations.xls");

        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the finally message show to me but i search on my computer but i can't find my excel file can any one help me with this in easy way

Comment: The SaveAs method for the filename specifies: Filename
The name of the file to be saved. You can include a full path; if you do not, Microsoft Office Excel saves the file in the current folder. - Where are you telling it to save in the location you are advising about? Search your project file, you may be creating it in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your data should match with data type which you have created in SQL Server.

```
using System.Data.OleDb; 
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

SQL

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
    GO 
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
    GO 
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON 
    GO 
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]( 
        [student] [varchar](50) NULL, 
        [rollno] [int] NULL, 
        [course] [varchar](50) NULL 
    ) ON [PRIMARY] 
    GO 
    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
    GO
```

C#

```
 public void ImportDataFromExcel(string excelFilePath) 
        { 
            //declare variables - edit these based on your particular situation 
            string ssqltable = "Table1"; 
            // make sure your sheet name is correct, here sheet name is sheet1, so you can change your sheet name if have    different 
            string myexceldataquery = "select student,rollno,course from [Sheet1$]"; 
            try 

            { 
                //create our connection strings 
                string sexcelconnectionstring = @"provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" + excelFilePath + 
                ";extended properties=" + "\"excel 8.0;hdr=yes;\""; 
                string ssqlconnectionstring = "Data Source=SAYYED;Initial Catalog=SyncDB;Integrated Security=True"; 
                //execute a query to erase any previous data from our destination table 
                string sclearsql = "delete from " + ssqltable; 
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring); 
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn); 
                sqlconn.Open(); 
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                sqlconn.Close(); 
                //series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our sql table 
                OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring); 
                OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn); 
                oledbconn.Open(); 
                OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader(); 
                SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring); 
                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable; 
                while (dr.Read()) 
                { 
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr); 
                } 
                dr.Close(); 
                oledbconn.Close(); 
                Label1.Text = "File imported into sql server."; 
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            { 
                //handle exception 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Well Where ever you want to call it, if it was me i would create a helper class, and invoke your methods from anywhere you want

Comment: I should select file from pc so i add Open-dialog to select file and make a button to select it this is the code of button how i can send file to this method
 `OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
            op.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;* xlsx;*xlsm";
            if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                return;
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(op.FileName, FileMode.Open);
            IExcelDataReader excelreader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            DataSet result = excelreader.AsDataSet();`

Comment: public void ImportDataFromExcel(string excelFilePath) , is a method that you can send file path to it and then it should work with your SQL table, if  your data should match with data type which you have created in SQL Server.

Comment: in this code i should have the file path but i have file itself(file stream)because there isn't FileUpload tool in C# windows form so i use button  to open opendialog , open dialog send the file itself not path so how can i send the file path to this method

Comment: I would recommend, you read this [FileStream Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx)   what is the reason you are using file stream? just to inform you file path is where you file is located, like  C:\user\file\test.json , you need to use file path even if you are using file stream, if you want to use file stream (Reading the file) you can loop the data and save the item in SQL

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty generic question.  Usually this site is best for very specialized questions where you can't find a solution, even after conducting several Google searches.  At least, that's what I think.

EXPORT FROM SQL SERVER TO EXCEL:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn ;
            string connectionString = null;
            string sql = null;
            string data = null;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0; 

            Excel.Application xlApp ;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            connectionString = "data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;user id=username;password=password;";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Product";
            SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dscmd.Fill(ds);

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);

            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls");
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Also . . .

EXPORT FROM EXCEL TO SQL SERVER:

```
// if you have Excel 2007 uncomment this line of code 
        //  string excelConnectionString =string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0",path); 

        string ExcelContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; 
        string Excel2010ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"; 
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile) 
        { 
            //Check the Content Type of the file 
            if(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType==ExcelContentType || FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType==Excel2010ContentType) 
            { 
                try 
                { 
                    //Save file path 
                    string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/TempFiles/"), FileUpload1.FileName); 
                    //Save File as Temp then you can delete it if you want 
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(path); 
                    //string path = @"C:\Users\Johnney\Desktop\ExcelData.xls"; 
                    //For Office Excel 2010  please take a look to the followng link  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/0f03c2de-3ee2-475f-b6a2-f4efb97de302/#ae1e6748-297d-4c6e-8f1e-8108f438e62e 
                    string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path); 

                    // Create Connection to Excel Workbook 
                    using (OleDbConnection connection = 
                                 new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)) 
                    { 
                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand 
                                ("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection); 

                        connection.Open(); 

                        // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet 
                        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()) 
                        { 

                            // SQL Server Connection String 
                            string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ExcelDB;Integrated Security=True"; 

                            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server 
                            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = 
                                       new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString)) 
                            { 
                                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Employee"; 
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr); 
                                Label1.Text = "The data has been exported succefuly from Excel to SQL"; 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 

                catch (Exception ex) 
                { 
                    Label1.Text = ex.Message; 
                } 
            } 
        }
```